# How can i solve the Counting Cards exercice of freecodecamp with my code?

Tags: javascript

problem statement is here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards

the problem comes when i tried to get 0 Hold in the return by the Cards Sequence 7, 8, 9 ,but i can't. I know that there are better options for solving this problem, but i wanna do it this way, someone can help?

---

````
function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
if (card = ( 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 )) {
  count += 1;
}
else if (card = ( 7 || 8 || 9 )) {
  count += 0;
}
else if (card = ( 10 || "J" || "Q"|| "K" || "A" )) {
  count -= 1;
}

if (count <= 0) {
  return count + " Hold";
}

else if (count > 0) {
  return count + " Bet";
}
  // Only change code above this line
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');```
````

Comment: Post the problem statement in your question. Links rot. If freecodecamp ever goes away or is blocked, then your question won't make sense to future visitors.

Comment: "the problem comes when i tried to get 0 Hold in the return." What does that mean?  Also, you can't do your `||` statements like that.  You'd need to do something like `if (card == 2 || card == 3 || card == 4...)`.  Furthermore, `=` does assignment; `==` and `===` do equality checks. Use them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the same gist of your function:

```
function cc(card) {
    if ("23456".indexOf(card) >= 0) count++;
    if ("10JQKA".indexOf(card) >= 0) count--;
    return count + (count <= 0 ? " Hold" : " Bet");
}
```